# Forces on an Alpha Particle travelling close to a nucleus

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, scattering

[image]

Above is a picture of a diagram, figure 3 showing an alpha particle fired past a lead nucleus.

The question stated:

***Figure 3 shows the path of an alpha particle close to the nucleus of lead. Draw arrows to represent the force on the alpha particle when at points A, B and C.***

I was unsure how to do this. 
You can see from my picture an attempt to draw arrows of force from the centre of the particle at A, B and C.

Have I done this correctly?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're totally right. The forces that exist in this process are electrostatic and electrostatic forces are central forces. Thats means that the direction of the force is the line which goes through the center of the both particles and in this case, the nucleus is positive charged and alpha particles too, so the force is repulsive and tries to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Direction of the force is the line which goes through the center of the both particles. In this case, both the nucleus and the alpha particles are positively charged, so the force is repulsive and tries to separate them.

Comment: Welcome! Note that we are [not a homework-help site](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714), and complete answers to homework-like questions (such as this one) are frequently deleted.